# TypeError: OAuthStrategy requires a consumerKey option

Tags: twitter, oauth

I keep getting this error when I added the twitter OAuth to my application. I currently have google OAuth which works fine, but adding twitter is causing the error. I don't see viable solution in all the previous posts on this error; can anyone help please? here is the code snippet for the twitter- it is the same as the google one.

```
passport.use(
  new TwitterStrategy({
      twitterclientID: keys.twitterclientID,
      twitterclientSecret: keys.twitterclientSecret,
      callbackURL: '/auth/twitter/callback',
      proxy: true
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Replace `twitterclientID` with `consumerKey`
&
Replace `twitterclientSecret` with `consumerSecret`

Recently google also does the same thing so you need to update for google as well since you are using google oauth

```
passport.use(
  new TwitterStrategy({
      consumerKey: theClientID,
      consumerSecret: theClientSecret,
      callbackURL: '/auth/twitter/callback',
      proxy: true
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
passport.use(
  new TwitterStrategy({
      consumerKey: keys.twitterclientID,
      consumerSecret: keys.twitterclientSecret,
      callbackURL: '/auth/twitter/callback',
      proxy: true
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had already declared `consumerKey` and `consumerSecret`. The issue for me was, that the environment variables used as the values for both keys, were not defined.

If you use netlify the issue may be solved after running `netlify link`.